# Executing side effect code inside scala for-comprehension block

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

How can I execute a side-effect code inside for-comprehension block? If I have something like this:

```
for {
 data <- fetchData()
} yield data.someAttribute
```

...and now I want to execute some code using foreach

```
for {
     data <- fetchData()
     someList <- fetchList(data)
     somelist.foreach(....)
} yield data.someAttribute
```

Comment: `_ = somelist.foreach(....)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply:

```
for {
     data <- fetchData()
     someList <- fetchList(data)
     _ = somelist.foreach(....)
} yield data.someAttribute
```

Comment: I infact started with same, but I get error: value map is not a member of Unit

Comment: @Mandroid Typo - I edited :)